# Copying string:while loop breaks on the first condtion only using C

Tags: c, string, while-loop, copy

I want to copy a string and want to stop copying either the next character is '\0' or '.'
so I wrote

```
while((dest[i]=src[i])!='\0'||src[i]=='.');
i++;
```

when the character is '\0' the while loop works perfectly
but in case of '.'
must I write a separate "if condition" for the second part ?and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an infinite loop there.

```
while((dest[i]=src[i])!='\0'||src[i]=='.');  // This is the end of the loop,
                                             // with an empty statement.
```

Also, you need to change the conditional a little bit.

```
(dest[i]=src[i]) != '\0' && src[i] != '.'
```

To avoid the empty statement problem after `while` and `if` statements, you can change your coding standard so that you always use the `{}`.

```
while ( (dest[i]=src[i]) != '\0' && src[i] != '.' )
{
   ++i
}
```